# AWS IAM Api for Policy Summary and Access Advisor info

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to fetch the list of services that is allowed by a role. I see the AWS console has the Access Advisor information which fits my needs but I see no API support. Anyone know a way to call policy summary call (or something similar) that can provide that information without having to do this manually on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no API call that provides information similar to the Access Advisor.

The closest option is the ability to fetch the IAM policy, but you would then need to interpret the policy into something human-intelligible.

Comment: right - almost seems weird that there is no good policy parser for AWS. Doing it manually that way seems very inefficient - wondering how the AWS Console loads it so quickly - probably a cached layer or something.