# Classify IAM Policies

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Is it possible to get the policy summary view like -

[image: Policy Summary View]

or have each individual IAM action be classified into -

- List: List resources in the service
- Read: Read resource content in the service
- Write: Create, delete, or modify resources in the service
- Permissions management: Grant or modify resource permissions in the
  service
- Full access: Encompasses all the above actions.

using the AWS boto3 library or some kind of other mechanism.

Right now I have the policies in the json format and I am trying to generate a view similar to Policy summary which can tell me what type of services does this policy provision access to.

I tried looking through the documents suggested by AWS - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#id380
And stackoverflow threads - [AWS IAM Api for Policy Summary and Access Advisor info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297398/aws-iam-api-for-policy-summary-and-access-advisor-info)

but based on these it does not seem as if this possible via the boto3 api(Please correct me if this is not true anymore) is there an alternative that can be used?

Comment: No, I don't think this is available. I suspect the summary you see there is being done programmatically by he AWS console parsing the policies and mapping actions/resources to higher-level descriptions. You could probably do something similar without huge effort.

Comment: @jarmod even if I wanted to do that where can I get like a list of all actions for all the services? Is there like a role or policy or place that would give me all the actions for the services so that I can tie them to a higher level descriptions ?

Comment: I think you would have to make broad generalizations like iam:* means IAM with Full access, iam:Get* means IAM with Read access, sqs:List.. or sqs:Describe... means SQS with List access, etc.

Comment: @jarmod Well, there is a difference between reading and listing as shown by AWS. For EC2 service DescribeAccountAttributes is part of List while DescribeElasticGpus is part of the Read group. Both start with Describe but if I did that it wouldn't be accurate, but would only help in broad classification.